# ActiveDataProvider display value yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, dataprovider

i just want to know that is it possible to display data of `$dataprovider` independent of any gridview.

Like if the `$dataprovider` contains value of a particular query result than it will be stored as array in that.

So how can i call only one value from `$dataprovider`

For example my `$dataprovider` contains value of all `select * from user where status=10`
so is it possible just to display `$dataprovider->user>name` just first record.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly access `$dataProvider->models` as suggested by scaisEdge and get the single model you need, but that is not very efficient, because it executes the query and retrieves *all* models only to be discarded later.

You can, however, get access to `dataProvider`'s `query` object, and with it get the single model you need.

```
$newQuery = clone $dataProvider->query;
$model = $newQuery->limit(1)->one();
```

Cloning the query is not necessary if it's ok to modify the `dataProvider` (if you don't use it anywhere else).

UPDATE:

`$this->title = isset($dataProvider->models[0]->name) ? $dataProvider->models[0]->name : 'empty result';`

Comment: i have only one concern. I want to display my `$dataprovider` first column's first item as page title.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, а то я считал, что клонировать датапровайдер это костыльное решение ))

Comment: Не сам датапровайдер, а запрос в нем. Кстати, постраничный вывод в датапровайдере так и сделан - путем клонирования запроса.

Answer (score 1):

Yes inside a dataProvider you can find the `models`. These are a collection of model and then if you iterate over this collection you can use the single model data e.g.:

```
 foreach( $dataProvider->models as $myModel){
    echo myModel->field1;
    echo myModel->filed2:
    ........ // and so on for all the data you need

 }
```

You can see this Yii2 framework  [doc for ref](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-activedataprovider.html)